# Problem uploading image(s) to EE question, “invalid request”

Tags: support, bug

Can’t upload image of a transformer to EE.SE right now. App says “invalid request”.
[image: ohno]

Comment: If you're talking about [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/416590/11683), has the issue now been resolved?

Comment: No. App is for iOS, latest version.

Comment: What is the image you're trying to upload?

Comment: Same as the one I already uploaded. Tried to upload it here, same error.